# Preparing a resume/portfolio with two experience fields

Tags: resume, skills, projects, portfolio

I am a full-stack web developer with projects in production and I'm also a data scientist who is studying Master of Data Science. I'm now focused on data science but I consider both fields important for me, and **I'm open to work in any of them**.

The question is that when I create my resume and my portfolio, how should I list the skills and the projects?

- Which skills/projects to list first?
- Should I create a section for web-development skills/projects and another section for data-science skills/projects?
- Should I create two versions of my resume, one for web development and one for data science? But isn't it better to show that I'm good in both fields by keeping one resume? Won't this option complicate things since I will need two web pages for each resume and two web pages for each portfolio?

I'm open to new solutions as well...

**Edit**: This is my current resume, if needed: http://ammar-alyousfi.com/pages/resume/en/

Answer (score 3):

**Write two versions.**

One for job offers seeking web developers and another for data scientists.

List your qualifications and experience with the according emphasis.

Still mention all your experience and education, they're part of your skillset in general.

Comment: Yep this is a good approach.  Heck when I was looking, I would customize my resume for each opening I applied.

Comment: This is the answer I would've given +1

Comment: Can you mention the reasons why not create a section for each field on the same resume/portfolio?